# WHM - php.ini in public_html stops default php.ini

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, php.ini

I have a server with WHM panel. OS is CentOS. When I put a `php.ini` in public_html PHP stops reading `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`.

When I compare results of phpinfo() what I see is;

> error_log error_log   error_log

becames

> error_log no value    no value

How can PHP reads master php.ini directives unless I add a directive in local php.ini.

PS: COPPYING MASTER php.ini CONTENT TO LOCAL php.ini IS NOT AN OPTION.

Comment: Please share more about why copying the master file is not an option.  If we understand this constraint we might be able to better help.

Comment: @Dan; Because I have 30 Web sites on my Web server. I don't want to do it every time I add a new site.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: you can't:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391808/how-do-i-include-a-php-ini-file-in-another-php-ini-file

However, you can put php ini directives into an .htaccess file:

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Or use ini_set function within your application itself:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: I know but my suPHP doesn't let me to use php_value in .htaccess

Comment: Any luck with "ini_set" in your app?  I've used this extensively to develop apps that try to be compatible with various hosting environments.

Comment: Dan my problem is when my customer puts a php.ini in his folder I want master directives are still active.

Comment: I, too, wish this were possible.  When I update our default php.ini configs, I manually look through all custom php.ini files to apply my changes, if they are not in conflict with any client customizations.

Tedious indeed.  I hope you find an answer for both of us.